# Crawl two different pages separately with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to crawl two URLs with the same spider: example.com/folder/ and example.com/folder/fold2 and retrieve two different things for each url.

start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/folder', 'http://www.example.com/folder/fold2']

1) check something for /folder
2) check something different for /folder/fold2

Comment: And what is your exact problem? Have you tried something?

Comment: The crawler checks in both URLs the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to override the [start_requests](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method instead of using start_urls:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request('http://www.example.com/folder',
                      callback=self.parse_folder)
        yield Request('http://www.example.com/folder/fold2',
                      callback=self.parse_subfolder)

    # ... define parse_folder and parse_subfolder here
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer, I will do as soon as I do! Thanks!